# Can not create database from the console

Tags: h2

I just installed h2-console windows version
and tried to create a database from taskbar - Create a new Database,
then It says error
入出力例外: "C:/Program Files (x86)/H2/bin/test.mv.db"
IO Exception: "C:/Program Files (x86)/H2/bin/test.mv.db" [90028-220]

Do I have to setting something?
Help me please

-Tried to~
I can access http://localhost:8082/
but
can not login says error
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-220] 90149/90149 (ヘルプ)
I guess the reason is nodatabase

When I access h2-console from taskbar-H2-Console,I can not access the page
It says
「このサイトにアクセスできません」(I can't access this site)

Comment: Is the database a file or is it in-memory? Because mem:testdb would be for an inmemory database, but the exception message has a file path. You have to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself
When you want to file db, you have to create from taskbar - H2-Console
For example
file:~/test
and next
change JDBC URL to
jdbc:h2:~/test